# I want to zoom image but inside the div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to zoom the image inside the div but when I am trying to zoom the image the size of the div is also increasing.

`<img src="" alt="Image Preview" id="zoom" class="image-preview__image">`

```
   <div class="btn-group mt-2" role="group" aria-label="">
            <button ng-click="Size=100" class="btn btn-sm btn-group btn-outline-info" onclick="zoomout()" >100%</button>
            <button ng-click="Size=200"  class="btn btn-sm btn-group btn-outline-info"  onclick="zoomin()" >200%</button>
            <button ng-click="Size=300" class="btn btn-sm btn-group btn-outline-info">300%</button>
            <button ng-click="Size=400" class="btn btn-sm btn-group btn-outline-info">400%</button>
            </div>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

   function zoomin() {
        var GFG = document.getElementById("zoom");
        var currHeight = GFG.clientHeight;
            GFG.style.height = (currHeight + 40) + "px";
    }
    function zoomout() {
        var GFG = document.getElementById("zoom");
        var currHeight = GFG.clientHeight;
            GFG.style.height = (currHeight - 40) + "px";
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the width/height, you can use the `transform` property to `scale` the image. If you place that image inside a container with `overflow:hidden`, you can resize the image to any size you like without it overflowing the container and the image will retain its original size for layout purposes.

With that said, you don't need a container with overflow hidden, but without one, the image will visually grow to whatever size you specify, though it will still maintain the intrinsic layout size.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let size = this.getAttribute("ng-click").split("=")[1];
    let image = document.getElementById("zoom");
    image.style.transform = `scale(${size}%)`;
  });
});
```

```css
.image-container
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img
{
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group mt-2" role="group" aria-label="">
  <button ng-click="Size=100" class="btn btn-sm btn-group btn-outline-info">100%</button>
  <button ng-click="Size=200" class="btn btn-sm btn-group btn-outline-info">200%</button>
  <button ng-click="Size=300" class="btn btn-sm btn-group btn-outline-info">300%</button>
  <button ng-click="Size=400" class="btn btn-sm btn-group btn-outline-info">400%</button>
</div>

<div class="image-container">
  <img alt="Image Preview" id="zoom" class="image-preview__image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect @Liftoff But why the image is not getting on the side when I am trying to do the side its zoom only middle ?

Comment: You can change where the image scales from using [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

Comment: Sorry to ask but how @Liftoff

Comment: I tried but didn't work @Liftoff

Comment: I want to move image after zoom @Liftoff

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If it's too long form for a comment, you should post a new question.

Comment: okk wait @Liftoff